# Call gtag_report_conversion on button click

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, gtag.js

I need to trigger the gtag_report_conversion function when my button is clicked.

Here is the function code:

```
<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
var callback = function () {
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
window.location = url;
}
};
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
'send_to': 'AW123456/AW123456',
'event_callback': callback
});
return false;
}
</script>
```

Here is my code which does not trigger once the button has been clicked.

```
    <div class="header-button">
    <a onclick="return gtag_report_conversion(‘https://google.com');" href="google.com" class="button plain is-outline is-small" style="border-radius:1px;">
    <span>Book Now</span>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could just trigger the *gtag_report_conversion* function **onclick**. see below.

`<a onclick="gtag_report_conversion();" class="button plain is-outline is-small" style="border-radius:1px;">`